# apache2 mysql authentication module and SHA1 encryption

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql

I found myself in a setup on where I need to enable some authentication method using mysql.

I already have an user scheme. That user scheme is working like a charm with MD5 password and CRYPT, but when I turn to SHA1sum it says:

```
[Fri Oct 26 00:03:20 2012] [error] Unsupported encryption type:
Sha1sum
```

No useful debug informations on log files.

This is my setup and some info:

debian6

apache and ssl installed packages:

```
root@sistemichiocciola:/etc/apache2/mods-available# dpkg --list | grep apache 
ii  apache2                            2.2.16-6+squeeze8           Apache HTTP Server metapackage
ii  apache2-mpm-prefork                2.2.16-6+squeeze8           Apache HTTP Server - traditional non-threaded model
ii  apache2-utils                      2.2.16-6+squeeze8           utility programs for webservers
ii  apache2.2-bin                      2.2.16-6+squeeze8           Apache HTTP Server common binary files
ii  apache2.2-common                   2.2.16-6+squeeze8           Apache HTTP Server common files
ii  libapache2-mod-auth-mysql          4.3.9-13+b1                 Apache 2 module for MySQL authentication
ii  libapache2-mod-php5                5.3.3-7+squeeze14           server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
root@sistemichiocciola:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# dpkg --list | grep ssl
ii  libssl-dev                         0.9.8o-4squeeze13           SSL development libraries, header files and documentation
ii  libssl0.9.8                        0.9.8o-4squeeze13           SSL shared libraries
ii  openssl                            0.9.8o-4squeeze13           Secure Socket Layer (SSL) binary and related cryptographic tools
ii  openssl-blacklist                  0.5-2                       list of blacklisted OpenSSL RSA keys
ii  ssl-cert                           1.0.28                      simple debconf wrapper for OpenSSL
```

my vhost setup:

```
AuthMySQL On

Auth_MySQL_Host localhost
Auth_MySQL_User XXX
Auth_MySQL_Password YYY
Auth_MySQL_DB users

AuthName "Sistemi Chiocciola Sezione Informatica"
AuthType Basic
#  require valid-user
require group informatica
Auth_MySQL_Encryption_Types Crypt Sha1sum
AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
AuthUserFile /dev/null

Auth_MySQL_Password_Table users
Auth_MYSQL_username_field email
Auth_MYSQL_password_field password
AuthMySQL_Empty_Passwords Off
AuthMySQL_Group_Table http_groups
Auth_MySQL_Group_Field user_group
```

Have I missed a package/configuration or something?

Comment: How have you performed the configuration using md5?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the encryption types are case sensitive, in which case it should be `SHA1Sum` like this:

```
Auth_MySQL_Encryption_Types Crypt SHA1Sum
```

Comment: I was pretty sure I had tried almost all "case" cases! Thank you!!